# How to call an API every 5 minutes using React?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I've been trying to call the API every 5 min but the limit for setInterval doesn't allow that.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      (() => {
        const API_KEY = "C5EQJXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const name = "FB";
        axios
          .get(
            `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${name}&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}`
          )
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data["Time Series (5min)"]);
            for (let key in data["Time Series (5min)"]) {
              setStocksX((prev) => [...prev, key]);
              setStocksY((prev) => [
                ...prev,
                data["Time Series (5min)"][key]["1. open"]
              ]);
            }
            //console.log(stocksX, stocksY);
          });
      })();
    }, 30000);
  });
```

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: what limit are you referring to?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: 5 minutes is `300000` in milliseconds; you specific `30000` which is half a minute or every 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I actually thought that there was like a 1 min max limit to setInterval().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add setInterval with 60 * 5 * 1000 of time, in useEffect hook in first renderization. After you need clear setInterval when unmount component.

```
const ref = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
  ref.current = setInterval(yourFunction, 5 * 60 * 1000);

  return () => {
    if(ref.current){
      clearInterval(ref.current)
    }
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this utility hook that I use in my React apps all the time:

```
import React from 'react';

type IntervalCallback = () => void;

function useDispatch(callback: IntervalCallback, delay: number): void {
  const cachedCallback = React.useRef<IntervalCallback>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    cachedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (delay !== 0) {
      const id = setInterval(() => cachedCallback?.current?.(), delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export const IntervalHooks = {
  useDispatch,
};
```

I can then use it as such:

```
IntervalHooks.useDispatch(() => { console.log("hello"); }, 300000);
```

This gives me a lot of flexibility since I can dynamically update my interval if needed, and takes care of clean up when my component gets unmounted.

Comment: This is very useful
Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I presume that your hook is declaring a new setInterval every 0.5 seconds, possibly making your React App stop in order to avoid memory leak, you just need to declare one `setInterval`, this means that the second parameter of `useEffect` should have empty squared brackets

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(yourFunction, 300000); // The function will be called
  },[]);                               // every 5 minutes
```